# Quiz! I have some issues with Arrays

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have to make a quiz game. I need to transfer the quiz().correct number. I tried to use index as number that I could transfer to make this work, but it doesn't work.

```
       ElseIf IntQ = 9 Then
        Quiz(8).Question = "On what channel did __________ first air?"
        Quiz(8).Ans1 = "BBC"
        Quiz(8).Ans2 = "BBC One"
        Quiz(8).Ans3 = "BBC Two"
        Quiz(8).Correct = 2
        Quiz(8).Used = False
        lblprompt.Text = Quiz(8).Question
        lblAnswer1.Text = Quiz(8).Ans1
        lblAnswer2.Text = Quiz(8).Ans2
        lblAnswer3.Text = Quiz(8).Ans3
        index = 8
```

This is what happens when you click on the label.

```
   Private Sub lblAnswer2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lblAnswer2.Click
    Dim quiz(9) As Quiz

    If quiz(index).Correct = 2 Then
        lblprompt.Text = "CORRECT  - You EARNED 2 Bananas"
        form1.Extermination += 2
    Else
        lblprompt.Text = "That is NOT the answer  - You LOST 2 BANANAS"
        form1.Extermination -= 2
    End If
```

The index doesn't work. So I'm hoping to find something to do.

Comment: Where have you defined index?

Comment: @utility It's a global statement

Comment: where are you setting value for index?

Comment: @utility   After every question, for example if question 1 is asked, then index =1.

Comment: place breakpoint and check the value of index that is passed

Comment: @utility    Already done that, the index is passed down fine. I thought that was the issue at the beginning.

Comment: check value of quiz(index).Correct in intermediate window

Comment: you are checking the value of quiz(index).Correct to 2 right ? ..place breakpoint and check the value of quiz(index).Correct

Comment: @utility Yes, I've placed breakpoints and the value is passed down correctly.

Comment: So you are telling that "quiz(index).Correct " gives a value '2' ? then you should get You EARNED 2 Bananas

Comment: @utility The index value is passed down but I tried it right now and even If I get specific ex. Quiz(1).correct = 1, it doesn't work. So I'm working on it right now.

Comment: keep break on  If quiz(index).Correct = 2 Then and run app.when break just tell ll guide you'

Comment: @utility okay, I've done that.

Comment: minimise your app..and you can see intermediate window in visual studio

Comment: type : ?quiz(index).Correct in that window

Comment: @utility okay, done.

Comment: after typing hit enter ,whats the value of quiz(index).Correct ?

Comment: @utility Index is 9 but pressing enter just moves the line down.

Comment: so the condition quiz(index).Correct = 2 is not matched

Comment: @utility There's 10 questions in the array. The index matched the index of the question.The quiz().correct answer is supposed to equal to 2 though but it still responses as if the correct answer is wrong.

Comment: What did you get the value of : quiz(index).Correct from intermediate window?